# Nexus 2 OSS proxy repository to public E404 with scoped packages

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy, nexus, nexus2

I have a problem with an instance of Nexus 2 OSS (2.11.4) trying to download a scoped package from the public npm registry via proxy repository.

In particular I set up a private (npm-private) and a proxy repo to npm public registry (npm-proxy) and added in to a group repo (npm-group), then I try to make an npm install of a public scoped package but I encountered this error
[image]

I tried also to set **AllowEncodedSlashes On** on my httpd apache server that is in front of the instance but seems not working. Any suggestions ?

P.S. my npmrc file is correctly set up because I'm able to download no scoped packages from the public registry via proxy for example

Thanks in advance